# Setstate going haywire when dispatch is triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm practicing building something similar to reddit using Reactjs and Firestore. However, when I click the upvote button, and trigger the dispatch to increate the score of the post, the post re-renders and component's state's id property becomes undefined.

A screenshot of my console log where id magically becomes undefined :(
[image]

```
class PostCard extends Component {

  state = {
    id: this.props.post.id,
    score: this.props.post.score,
    upVoted: false
  }

  upVoteClicked = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    if (!this.state.upVoted) {
      this.props.upVote(this.state);  // without this dispatch function, it works perfectly
      const currentScore = this.state.score;
      const newScore = currentScore + 1;
      this.setState({
        score: newScore,
        upVoted: true
      });
    } else {
      const currentScore = this.state.score;
      const newScore = currentScore - 1;
      this.setState({
        score: newScore,
        upVoted: false
      });
    }
  }

render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    const { title, content, imgUrl} = this.props.post;

    return(
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col s12'>
          <div className='card'>
            <div className='card-image'>
              <img src={imgUrl}/>
            </div>
            <div className='card-content row'>
              <div className='col s2'>
                <div className={this.state.upVoted ? 'red-text center' : 'center'} onClick={this.upVoteClicked}>
                  <i className='small material-icons pointer-cursor'>arrow_drop_up</i>
                  <p>{this.props.post.score}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='col s10'>
                <span className="card-title">{title}</span>
                <p>{content}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    upVote: (postDetails) => dispatch(upVote(postDetails))
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostCard);
```

the component above is called by this parent component:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

  render() {
    const { posts, auth } = this.props;
    //post cards returned here
    const list = posts && posts.map(post => {
      return(
        <PostCard key={post.id} post={post}/>
      );
    })


    if(!isLoaded(auth)) {
      var rightBar = <p>Loading</p>
    } else {
      if (!auth.uid) {
        rightBar = <AuthCard/>
      } else {
        rightBar = <SignedInCard userName={auth.email}/>
      }
    }

    return(
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col s8'>
            {list}
          </div>
          <div className='col s4 sticky'>
            {rightBar}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    posts: state.firestore.ordered.posts
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'posts', orderBy: ['score', 'desc']}
  ])
)(Dashboard);
```

the imported upVote action is as follow:

```
export const upVote = (postDetails) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const newScore = postDetails.score + 1;
    firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc(postDetails.id).update({
      score: newScore,
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch({type: 'UPVOTE_SUCCESS'})
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({type: 'UPVOTE_ERROR', error:err})
    })
  }
}
```

and its reducer is as follow:

```
const postReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPVOTE_SUCCESS':
      console.log('Upvote Success!')
      return state;
    case 'UPVOTE_ERROR':
      console.log('Upvote Error', action.error)
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My questions:

1. I heard it is not right to set properties of your state to prop's value, but has this issue got to do with that? If so, how should i restructure it?
2. Is it possible to not re-render the component when I trigger the dispatch function, but still be able to update the score in the post component?

Comment: First of all, your code looks great! I'm happy to see how tidy it is :) To answer your second question, you can always use `shouldComponentUpdate` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to control re-renders based on props and state changes. That said, I think we might be missing some context to understand what the problem is. It looks like you are importing an `upVote` action, correct? What does this action and the reducer look like? Could you share more code from the parent component as well? There could be something there that makes things go awry.

Comment: @YvesGurcan thank you for your encouraging words :) I've updated my question with the action, reducer, and parent component. Really appreciate you looking into my issue!

Comment: I mean it! The code you added after updating your question also looks great. Nothing stands out to me as an obvious problem. I will try to reproduce this bug later but I won't be able to look into it for the next 12 hours. Hopefully, somebody else will have found the problem by then. Otherwise, I will let you know if I find anything. Keep working on it! You'll figure it out :)

Comment: @YvesGurcan Take your time. Thank you! I've added a picture of my console log if it helps :)

Comment: Not sure if Im understanding the logic of `mapDispatchToProps`: `upVote` function receives `postDetails`, it uses it to update firebase and then returns a function that receives a dispatch? Shouldn't it return the action?

Comment: @Alvaro i believe upvote is the action, and when executed triggers the dispatch.

Comment: Maybe Im just reading it incorrectly. I would try not returning anything, and passing the dispatch to it, so: `upVote: (postDetails) => upVote(dispatch,postDetails)` and then `const upVote = (dispatch,postDetails) => { const newScore = postDetails.score + 1...`. But I would still do the fetch differently. Hope it can help.

Comment: @Alvaro Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it, the id still goes missing after the upvote :/

Comment: Thanks. It looks like you're using Firebase with your Redux store. Did you look into that? That could be the source of the issue.

Comment: @YvesGurcan it could be, but i don't know where to start looking.. i've tried many search terms but to no avail :/

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I couldn't get around a computer today to look into your code. I should be able to work on it tomorrow! Sounds like this bug might be a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Why do you have a post reducer if all your actions just return state? That seems redundant. If you are just dispatching an action to fire off a thunk then no reducer is necessary for those actions. This will definitely cause a redundant re-render. Also, you have `firestoreConnect` as a selector. What is this? Can you share the code for that or is it from a package? Does it propagate collection changes in real-time, or do you need to manually pull the new changes from firebase (because that doesn't seem to be happening anywhere).

Comment: @JoshPittman firestoreConnect is from react-redux-firebase package. it propagates collection changes in real-time. i tried commenting out the dispatch and it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: commenting out the dispatch? What dispatch are you referring to? My point was that you should remove the redundant postReducer.

Comment: Alos, if you have redux dev tool can you please add a screen shotof what actions are being fired when this happen. Time travel to the error transition and let's see what the last action fired was.

Comment: @JoshPittman i did remove the postReducer, i commented out the 'dispatch({type: 'UPVOTE_SUCCESS'})' so that it doesn't call the reducer.

Comment: @JoshPittman i downloaded the redux dev tool but have trouble setting it up, it doesn't show anything. will continue clicking around

Comment: @YvesGurcan, i narrowed my problem down to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017073/firestore-document-id-missing-after-document-update